# Passing data from Word bookmark to field in Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am working on VBA code that passes data from an Access form (before saving the form in the table) to bookmarks in a Word document.

It works well, but the user may edit the Word document before saving it, so I need code to return data from the Word bookmark to the Access form (which was opened before). Let's say I will just pass one bookmark data to one field in the form, I need to clear the field then transfer data to it.

I see some ways to pass from Word to Access table, but I'm looking for passing to a form.

The code below for passing from Access to Word works well:

```
Private Sub Command68_Click()
Call fillWordForm
End Sub
```

---

```
    Function fillWordForm()

Dim appWord As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim path As String
Dim myID As String

On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear

Set appWord = CreateObject("word.application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set appWord = New Word.Application
appWord.Visible = True
End If

path = Application.CurrentProject.path & "\H_F.docx"


If FileExists(path) = False Then
MsgBox "Template File Not Found", vbExclamation, "File Not Found"
Else
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Add(path, , True)
myID = DLookup("ID", "Exports_imports_Table", "[ID] = " & Me.ID)
With doc
.FormFields("BookID").Result = [ID]
.FormFields("Book_BC_date").Result = Me.date_BC
.FormFields("Book_AH_date").Result = Me.date_AH
.FormFields("Book_AH_date").Result = Me.date_AH
.FormFields("BookTopic").Result = Me.topic
.FormFields("BookProjectName").Result = Me.projectName
.FormFields("BookCompanyName").Result = Me.companyName
.FormFields("BookContent").Range.Text = Me.content

'Result = Me.content

appWord.Visible = True
appWord.Active
End With
Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing

End If
End Function
```

---

```
Function FileExists(ByVal strFile As String, Optional bFindFolders As Boolean) As Boolean
'Purpose:   Return True if the file exists, even if it is hidden.
'Arguments: strFile: File name to look for. Current directory searched if no path included.
'           bFindFolders. If strFile is a folder, FileExists() returns False unless this argument is True.
'Note:      Does not look inside subdirectories for the file.
'Author:    Allen Browne. http://allenbrowne.com June, 2006.
Dim lngAttributes As Long

'Include read-only files, hidden files, system files.
lngAttributes = (vbReadOnly Or vbHidden Or vbSystem)

If bFindFolders Then
    lngAttributes = (lngAttributes Or vbDirectory) 'Include folders as well.
Else
    'Strip any trailing slash, so Dir does not look inside the folder.
    Do While Right$(strFile, 1) = "\"
        strFile = Left$(strFile, Len(strFile) - 1)
    Loop
End If

'If Dir() returns something, the file exists.
On Error Resume Next
FileExists = (Len(Dir(strFile, lngAttributes)) > 0)
End Function
```

Comment: You want Access VBA to open Word document and fill bookmarks, allow user to edit those data, and Access code pull those edits back to form - all in one session? I doubt it can be done. Access procedure does not suspend execution when Word doc opens. How could it be paused to allow user edits then resumed to retrieve the inputs? User should do all inputs to Access form then open Word doc only when satisfied with entries.

Comment: @June7 thanks for your reply, not in one session, for example, if I  click a button on word or if I save the word document the event of transfer will be executed (just clear field in access form and pass data to it)

Comment: Then you need code behind Word template document that automates Access, however, that means Word VBA has to open connection to an Access file that is already open. Don't know if that is possible. I expect there are examples of Word VBA to automate Access. You need to attempt code and when you have specific issue, post question. Seems like an unnecessarily complicated process. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. You'll need to replace my test strings with those appropriate for your environment (boomkark name, form name, control name).

Commented out is the line that would open a form, just because I have it and it could interest someone.

```
Sub AutomateAccessForm()
    Dim accApp As Access.Application
    Dim sData as String

    sData = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("X").Range.Text
    Set accApp = GetObject(, "Access.Application")
    '''    accApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "Source Bücher"

    accApp.DoCmd.GoToControl "Bemerkungen"
    accApp.Forms("Source Bücher").ActiveControl.SetFocus
    accApp.Forms("Source Bücher").ActiveControl.Text = sData
    Set accApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, how it was work with you? I mean where should I put this code in Word? and what you mean by control name? @cindy

Comment: Control name -> "field in the form". As to the first part, I think it would be better if you asked that as a new question, expaining how you imagine the functionality will be used. There are numerous options.

Comment: You mentioned using a button on Word document. Only button control I see available is an ActiveX type. I usually have difficulty with ActiveX controls but was rather simple on Word document. Dragged button control to Word document, right click > View Code, type code into procedure.